# Azure build pipeline (Power apps solution) run successfully but Artifact not displayed in Repo. but its displayed in pipeline artifact

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, powerapps, power-platform

Azure build pipeline run successfully but Artifact (folder and files) not displayed in Repo.
This is pipeline for Power apps solutions

I have mentioned the following paths for Solution export and import

Solution output file : $(Build.StagingDirectory)$(SolutionName)_Unmanaged.zip

Solution Input file : $(Build.StagingDirectory)$(SolutionName)_Unmanaged.zip

Target folder to unpack the solution : $(Build.StagingDirectory)$(SolutionName)\Unmanaged

target version : not given

I have bit doubt that these paths are created automatically

Publish to Artifact : $(Build.StagingDirectory)$(SolutionName)\Unmanaged

[Build pipeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rn4aR.png)

[Artifact published](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GnVGe.png) 
[Azure repo screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/96xiI.png)

Answer (score 0):

Azure Pipeline will clone the Repo to the agent, changes are made on the agent environment and will not sync to Repo automatically.

If you want the Artifact display in Repo, you could add a PowerShell task after your build tasks in your pipeline to push the change the Target Repo:

```
git push https://{PAT}@dev.azure.com/{OrgName}/{ProjName}/_git/{RepoName}
```